# SQlite query to search for a string in 2 columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to search for a string in 2 columns of my table. I want the row to be returned if the string is in either one of the two columns.

In the query, search_text is the string to be searched and KEY_TITLE and KEY_BODY are the two columns to be searched.

This searches the KEY_BODY:

```
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_DATE}, KEY_BODY + " LIKE '"+search_text+"%'" , null, null, null,KEY_DATE_INT + " DESC");
```

This searches KEY_TITLE:

```
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_DATE}, KEY_TITLE + " LIKE '"+search_text+"%'" , null, null, null,KEY_DATE_INT + " DESC");
```

I need a combination of the 2 results. I came up with this:

```
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_DATE}, 
            KEY_BODY + " LIKE '"+search_text+"%'"+ "||"
            + KEY_TITLE + " LIKE '"+search_text+"%'" 
            , null, null, null,KEY_DATE_INT + " DESC");
```

This doesn't return anything. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong with the query?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, `||` is a string concatenation operator and not logical-or. Suprisingly, the logical operator is `OR`:

```
KEY_BODY + " LIKE '"+search_text+"%' OR "
+ KEY_TITLE + " LIKE '"+search_text+"%'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use OR instead of ||

'"+search_text+"%'" means textANDSOMETHING

I guess you want SOMETHINGtextANDSOMETHING.

Use: '%"+search_text+"%'"